# Adding optional value to [Any], got compiler warning - expression implicitly coerced from Double? to Any

Tags: arrays, swift, swift3, any

I'm currently learning the type "Any" in swift and have come up with the following code

```
let optionalDouble: Double? = 45.1
let things: [Any] = [
    0,
    0.0,
    1.1,
    optionalDouble, //expression implicitly coerced from Double? to Any 
    -4.0,
    ("hello", 1),
    Movie(name: "Titanic", director: "James"),
    {(name: String) -> String in
        return "hello \(name)"
    },
    {},
    ["one": 1, "two": 2]
]
```

However, when I tried to add an optional `Double` value to the `[Any]` array, swift compiler displayed an warning saying

`//expression implicitly coerced from Double? to Any`

I thought type `Any` can represent everything and an array of type `[Any]` can contain everything. So why the warning message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's only a warning. The compiler wants to make sure you know you're doing an odd thing, wrapping an Optional inside an Any.

In the line that's giving trouble, write `optionalDouble as Any` to suppress the warning.

Comment: thank you very much for the explanation. I'm not sure this is count as a follow up question or deserve a post of its own, but what should I write when I want to check in a switch statement, to find out if the object inside [Any] is of optional Double type?

Comment: It's very difficult. That's exactly why they are warning you against doing that!

Comment: To be a little more expansive: you can easily learn that it is ultimately a Double, with `case is Double`. But to learn that it is a Double wrapped in an Optional — hmmm. You're not allowed to say `case is Optional<Double>` because that is a "more Optional type". You see the problem.

Comment: yeah, thats exact the error swift compiler showed to me, I guess I should just avoid using type Any unless absolutely necessary or until I can fully understand it.